# How to integrate PayPal in Klarna Payment Method

Tags: json, klarna

i am couldn't find anything, how to implement the PayPal payment option at the Klarna App, on their Website they have the PayPal button, but when i run the checkout sandbox api, i don't get the button...(https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/) Here is my Post request to https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders

```
{
    "purchase_country": "DE",
    "purchase_currency": "EUR",
    "locale": "de-DE",
    "order_amount": 50000,
    "order_tax_amount": 4545,
    "order_lines": [
        {
            "type": "physical",
            "reference": "19-402-USA",
            "name": "Red T-Shirt",
            "quantity": 5,
            "quantity_unit": "pcs",
            "unit_price": 10000,
            "tax_rate": 1000,
            "total_amount": 50000,
            "total_discount_amount": 0,
            "total_tax_amount": 4545
        }
        ],
    "merchant_urls": {
        "terms": "https://www.example.com/terms.html",
        "checkout": "https://www.example.com/checkout.html",
        "confirmation": "https://www.example.com/confirmation.html",
        "push": "https://www.example.com/api/push"
    },
    "external_payment_methods": [
    {
        "name": "PayPal",
        "redirect_url": "https://paypal.com/"
    }
    ]
}
```

or is paypal in the live environment automaticaly enabled or can be enabled in the dashboard?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, paypal has a sdk which works perfect.

Comment: Great! Can you please post the link to the sdk? Thank you very much 

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/

Comment: Hi, thanks! I can't find a special PayPal Klarna SDK via the link. How did you integrate PayPal as an external payment option in the Klarna Checkout?

Comment: Ahhh ok sry yea i made it but its more difficult, you have to write a hole PayPal integration and then you can simply link it to that url in klarna, so first you have to integrate the paypal into your Project then you will get a link from paypal and you can insert it at the klarna checkout. Then the user will get redirected to your paypal integration.